# Postman Twilio Rest Api

Tags: rest, twilio, postman

Hi I was wondering if someone could help me ,I am trying to use twilios' rest api and im running into some trouble. MyAccountIdSid,mySid and phone numbers are filled in in the actual request,Is there something i am doing wrong,
I get Your "AccountSid or AuthToken was incorrect" .
Can someone show me the correct way to make this request for sending an sms please.
I am trying to send a text message
Post Request Url i am using :

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/MyAccountIdSid/Messages.json


{
   "account_sid": "MyAccountIdSid",
   "api_version": "2010-04-01",
   "body": "HelloWorld",
   "num_segments": "1",
   "num_media": "1",
   "date_created": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:01:40 +0000",
   "date_sent": null,
   "date_updated": "Wed, 18 Aug 2010 20:01:40 +0000",
   "direction": "outbound-api",
   "error_code": null,
   "error_message": null,
   "from": "+353xxxxxxxx",
   "price": null,
   "sid": "mySID",
   "status": "queued",
   "to": "+353xxxxxxxxx",
   "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/MyAccountIdSid/Messages/mySid.json"
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you're copying it from [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), be aware that the first part of it is the request, and the second is the response, so what you're trying to send to Twilio is the response, hence why it's not working for you.

What you need to send to Twilio is the following:

```
$ curl -XPOST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json \
    -d "Body=Jenny%20please%3F%21%20I%20love%20you%20<3" \
    -d "To=%2B15558675309" \
    -d "From=%2B14158141829" \
    -d "MediaUrl=http://www.example.com/hearts.png" \
    -u 'AC36b9a6be2f98274fe61d15b63aabf1e0:{AuthToken}'
```

I've created a quick screeencast showing you how to do that with postman 2. Hope it helps you.

[image]

Comment: @Marcos Placona what was the header you used? For the 'Basic Auth' choice, are those your Postman credentials or your creds for Twilio?

Answer (score 11):

Note : Enhancement of Marcos Placona's Answer

In the Authorization section, set 'AUTH TOKEN' in 'password' field.
You can find 'AUTH TOKEN' just below Account Summary.

https://www.twilio.com/console

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20003

'Authenticate using your Account SID as the username, and your Auth Token as the password.'

Comment: You just answered my next question about which auth details to input. Thanks!

Comment: This should be added as an edit to the accepted answer. Pro tip: editing the accepted answer with a good addition will earn you points every time someone upvotes the accepted answer. Always a win!