# Using Postman to Test a Twilio Webtask

Tags: javascript, rest, http, twilio, postman

Trying to replace my workplace's Twilio implementation with a temporary solution while we move from one platform to another, and I thought Webtask would be a great solution. I was very happy to see that there was a default Twilio template for webtask and thought I could get straight to work but for some reason, I can't get the template to work even with it's default functionality.

I'm worried that I'm not posting what's expected to the webtask. Here's the default code that sits on my webtask:

```html
'use latest';
import twilio from 'twilio';
module.exports = (context, cb) => {
  // POST a json object with at least the following properties.
  const { body, to_number, from_number } = context.data;
  const { TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN } = context.secrets;
  
  var client = new twilio.RestClient(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
  client.messages.create({
    body,
    to_number,
    from_number
  }, (err, message) => {
    message = message + " Goodbye World!";
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, message);
  });
};
```

And here's what my Postman looks like (with my Twilio phone number and personal phone number supplied to from_number and to_number in the actual code obv).
Headers:
[postman-headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB4Zy.png) 
Body:
[postman-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzFl9.png)

I've stored my Auth token and SID in the secrets area. When I make this post, I receive:

```html
{
    "code": 400,
    "error": "Script returned an error.",
    "details": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "A 'From' phone number is required.",
        "code": 21603,
        "moreInfo": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603"
    },
    "message": "A 'From' phone number is required."
}
```

I've tried several things, like setting the from_number in the code like this `const from_number = "+19999999999"` except with a real number. Even so, I get the same 400 response (I also tried adding the SID as a username and the Auth Token as a password, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078510/postman-twilio-rest-api) -- same result). I really want to get webtask working, if at all possible.

Comment: May i see the twilio endpoint url ?

Comment: Try this way https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mYu.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you're making the call to Twilio to send the message you are using the wrong attribute names. Instead of

```
client.messages.create({
    body,
    to_number,
    from_number
  }, (err, message) => { //... } );
```

it should be:

```
client.messages.create({
    body,
    to: to_number,
    from: from_number
  }, (err, message) => { //... } );
```

Twilio expects the attributes to be called `to` and `from` not `to_number` and `from_number`.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This definitely did help. I ended up not using webtask, but this was a problem that would have persisted either way. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted! For the future, if you need a standalone solution for hosting an endpoint that does this kind of work, check out [Twilio Functions](http://twilio.com/functions) too.

Comment: That might be exactly what I need, thank you for the link. I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: No problems! Just let me know if you have any questions at all about it!